# Maintain the aspect ratio(Landscape/Portrait) of images clicked by device's camera

Tags: jssor

Got stuck in a issue with creating responsive slider. I have created slider and it's working fine. What is the issue is I am making slider for images clicked by camera.

There is a button under slider which clicks new image and then store that image in Database using SQLite and then It will fetch that images from Database and add into the slider.

It works fine with Landscape images clicked by camera. I'm getting portrait images clicked in slider but it's stretching the image with the width of slider. I want to know that how to maintain ratio of images in slider as I clicked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in your jssor slider options change $FillMode:

```
   $FillMode: 1   //1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide)
```

you'll find an example on the official website here: http://jssor.com/demos/different-size-photo-slider.slider

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried all Values of $FillMode in jssor slider but it's not working. Is it possible issue might be with the CSS or the size of the slider container?